# mount --bind nohide alike

Tags: linux, mount, kernel

I have some mounts under /mnt like other filesystems.
If I make a mount --bind /mnt/raid /export/raid, everything that have a mount on /mnt/raid/ don't appear under /export/raid.

I know I can use nohide for nfs, or even follow symlinks on samba, but couldn't find any option for bind. Is there any option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use --rbind instead of --bind:

---

**mount --bind olddir newdir**
After this call the same contents is accessible in two places.

This call attaches only (part of) a single filesystem, not possible
submounts. The entire file hierarchy including submounts is attached a
second place using
**mount --rbind olddir newdir**

Answer (score 2):

If you have some other filesystem mounted in `/mnt/raid/someotherfilesystem` then you need

```
mount --rbind /mnt/raid /export/raid
```

in order to recursively bind all of the other mounted filesystems.  `--bind` by itself "[attaches only (part of) a single filesystem](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount)"